# Is it possible to use google cloud run to implement the function of TTS that receiving http requests and send voice data responses?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-run

I want to create a function that receives an http request for text data and send response of voice data.

Specifically, I want to run TTS called tacotron2 at the following url on the cloud and receive the resulting voice.
https://github.com/NVIDIA/tacotron2

Is it possible to run a machine learning model using google cloud run and receive binary audio data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Run fully managed don't support the GPU. I would like to say not, except if the model can work (slowly) in a non GPU environment.

The alternative is to use Cloud Run for Anthos, on your own GKE cluster. In this case, you can choose the node pool configuration that you prefer, with GPU and you can. But it's not serverless, you have to manage yourselves the cluster and you have to pay it full time (don't scale to 0 like Cloud Run fully managed)